# How to change the displayed denomination in GreenBits Android wallet?

Tags: android, green-address, greenbits

I just installed GreenBits, the native Java wallet from GreenAddress.it, on my Android device and transferred 0.1 BTC to the wallet. I like it so far.

However, it displays my balance as `100,000 bits`. That's cool, but I would like to stick to a more commonly used display like `0.1 BTC`. All the news items say [you can chose](https://blog.greenaddress.it/2015/02/05/greenbits-the-all-new-snappy-android-bitcoin-wallet-with-multisig-and-hardware-wallets-support/):

> All bitcoin denominations (BTC, mBTC, uBTC *and* Bits)

But I can't find anyway to change it. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top right corner of GreenBits there's a menu with a number of entries: the first one is named "Settings" and we should select that, then "Info & settings" and then you can change the fiat currency, the bitcoin denomination as well as your preferred exchange if available.

Comment: I don't have that. I only see: Mnemonic passphrase, Auto logout timeout, Enable transaction replacement, Improve security with Ledger, Version (1.77 release). Maybe I'm blind?

Comment: You are not blind, it was changed in a later release. In that release you can change it from the Send tab by clicking on the bits text or to change fiat currency click on the $ USD icon. If you are using FDroid we have submitted a merge request to update GreenBits to the latest version https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroiddata/merge_requests/1663 and you can also download the latest version from our github release page

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Waiting for the update via FDroid. And +1 for providing FDroid releases :-)